# What's the fastest time complexity algorithm for finding maximal paths in an unweighted directed graph?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, directed-graphs

I see a lot of interest online to the problems of finding shortest paths, longest paths, and all simple paths. I'm interested in implementing a state-of-the-art algorithm to find all (simple) maximal paths of an directed graph without weights for an open-source package.

It may be useful for me to quickly demarcate some related concepts. By *maximal path*, I mean a path that cannot be made longer by prepending or appending vertices to it. The *maximum paths* are the longest paths among the maximal paths, but I am not asking about this subset. The *longest paths* between two vertices are the maximal paths between two vertices, and while they have an intersection with the maximal paths they are not identical concepts.

A naive approach would be to generate all simple paths and test the criterion. Another approach would be to find all longest paths between pairs of nodes, and then filter down. I am hopeful that there is a more efficient approach.

What algorithm would efficiently generate all the simple maximal paths of an unweighted directed graph?

Comment: There might be exponentially many maximal paths, so such an algorithm will necessarily be infeasible on many graphs; and we cannot evaluate such an algorithm based on its worse-case running time (as the worst-case running time will necessarily be horrible for all algorithms).  So how would you like to see candidate algorithms evaluated?  by what criteria?  by what metric do you want it to be state-of-the-art?

Comment: @D.W. I suspect you're right about the exponential number of (simple) maximal paths given that the simple paths problem itself is exponential, and that there will may be plenty of real-world networks that are too large for this algorithm to complete in a reasonable amount of time.

Comment: @D.W. There are different degrees of horrible, no? EXPTIME is better than 2-EXPTIME, for example.

Comment: @D.W. The primary criteria I would be interested in is time complexity (average, or worst case), but I could be convinced by real run times with information about the number of vertices, edges, and connectivity, if those are available.